# Change default phone number fields in Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

When you add new contacts, the default order for phone numbers is:

```
Business | Home | Business Fax | Mobile
```

Is there a way to change what these defaults are?

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't think there is a way to change the default order. However you can change the phone number type using the pick list.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by [customizing Contact's form](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/tutorial-creating-and-distributing-custom-forms-with-outlook-HA001210610.aspx). Tutorial shows the process for Outlook 2003, but for 2007 it's pretty much the same.